# Detecting two changing inharmonic pitches

Tags: fft, autocorrelation, pitch

I have a recording of a newer type of siren that uses two pitches sliding back and forth in time. I want to be able to detect both of the pitches simultaneously or overlapping at short intervals. Autocorrelation is not yielding good results in this case. Since I know the frequency range of interest for these pitches, is there a frequency-domain method that can be used to detect both pitches as they change?

[image: siren with two pitches]

Comment: is this problem intractable?

Comment: You can make it easier for people to help you by providing more information. For example, show a spectrogram of the recording.

Comment: noted, spectrogram has been added. my naive method that i haven't implemented would be: STFT -> pick first peak in band of interest (600 to 1700 Hz) -> ignore harmonics -> pick second peak. that would hopefully hint towards the two pitches.